# Run a slider of images in google map info window

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, anythingslider

I am trying to show a slider of images in Google Map info windows. but no error coming but slider is not working.

I want to do same as in picture.

```
 $(document).ready(function() { // runs jquery when document is ready

      function initialize() {

        var uluru = {
          lat: -25.363,
          lng: 131.044
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: uluru
        });

        var contentString = '<div id="content"><ul id="slider"><li><img src="demos/images/slide-civil-1.jpg" alt=""></li><li><img src="demos/images/slide-env-1.jpg" alt=""></li><li><img src="demos/images/slide-civil-2.jpg" alt=""></li><li><img src="demos/images/slide-env-2.jpg" alt=""></li></ul></div>';

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: contentString
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map,
          title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
        });
        marker.addListener('click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, function() {
          $('#slider').anythingSlider();

        });
      }
      initialize();

    });
```

[image]

Comment: you need to run `$('#slider').anythingSlider();` on the `domready` event of the infowindow (you are missing the event name in your event listener)

Comment: please make it ans, i want to give you +1 and accepted ans

Comment: and the one who give me -1 . come here and explain reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to run `$('#slider').anythingSlider();` on the `domready` event of the infowindow (you are missing the event name in your event listener)

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, "domready", function() {
      $('#slider').anythingSlider();
 });
```